# i verify that autocomplete works well but there are no results appear

Tags: python, selenium, search, autocomplete, assertion

I verify if Autocomplte works well or not. I send the keys but he does not select the required element. Finally I want to print the URL of the page that appear after finding the required element and pressing on it. I recieve only this result:

```
Ran 1 test in 33.110s
OK
Process finished with exit code 0
Message:
```

```
def test_autocomplet(self):
     try:
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver=webdriver.Chrome()
        url = self.driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php")
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        Serach_text_box=self.driver.find_element_by_id("search_query_top")
        Serach_text_box.send_keys("Printed")
        Serach_text_box.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
        five_option= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"//*[contains(text(),'Dress')]")))
        five_option.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        print self.driver.current_url
        self.assertEqual("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=3&controller=product",self.driver.current_url, "This Test case is fallied")
     except NoSuchElementException as e:
         print (e)
     except AssertionError as e:
         print (e)
     except TimeoutException as e:
         print (e)
```

I want to know if any thing in the code is wrong and why he does not select and click on the required element and print the URL of the next page that appear after click on the required element.

I would be thanksfull for any help.

Comment: don't you get any error message with `print(e)` ?

Comment: do you use Python 2 ? In Python 3 you need `()` in `print( self.driver.current_url )`

Comment: code works for me if I use full text `contains(text(),'Summer Dresses > ')` and later `five_option.click()`

Comment: code works with word `Dress` only if I search `<li>` which is used to build autocomplete  - `"//li[contains(text(),'Dress')]"` - but again I need `five_option.click()` to accept it and load new page.

Comment: BTW: when I get error `TimeoutException` then it prints `Message:` which you get in your output.  You would know that you get error if you would use ie. `print("TimeoutException:", e)`

Comment: BTW: if I use `time.sleep(1)` after `send_keys("Printed")` then autocomplete has time to open list and then I can use `search_text_box.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)` (many times) and `search_text_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)` to select element on the list.

Comment: Thanks very much for your support
- I don’t get Erro with e 
- I use python 2.7.13, So that I don’t need ( ) when i use 
print self.driver.current_url

Comment: - I get Time Except error when I get element with summer Dresses contains(text(),'Summer Dresses > ') and later five_option.click() and when I get element with (Dres)"//li[contains(text(),'Dress')]" –and later  five_option.click() .

Comment: And there are multiple elements (Summer Dresses). I need this Element Casual Dresses > Printed Dress . This Element is number five in Autocomplete suggestion

Comment: I don't use `five_option= ..` because it doesn't work. I used `Serach_text_box.send_keys("Printed")` and five times `Serach_text_box.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)` and `search_text_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)`

Comment: OR I have to use `"//li[contains(text(),'Dress')]"` to search it - and then I can use `click()`

Comment: Sorry-furas What should I add in this code to verify that the search keyword is highlighted in a certain color in the search results?

What should I add in this code to verify that, when user clicks on any link from result and navigates back, the result is maintained?

Comment: you can use `"xpath(//li[contains(text(),'Dress')])"` to select element in search results and then you can use `.text` to get full text in this selection. Or you can use xpath(`.//b`) to get  only highlighted part in selection.

Answer (score 0):

I put here code which I used to test this page.

---

To select item on menu I can use `ARROW_DOWN` but it doesn't give information about selected item.

Second method is to search

```
//div[@class='ac_results']//li[contains(text(),'Dress')]
```

or at least

```
//li[contains(text(),'Dress')]
```

eventually

```
//div[@class='ac_results']//li
```

to access item in menu. And then I can get full text `.text` or highlighted part `.//strong`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException
import time

try:
    #driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    url = driver.get("http://automationpractice.com/index.php")
    #driver.maximize_window()
    
    search_text_box = driver.find_element_by_id("search_query_top")
    
    search_text_box.send_keys("Printed")
    time.sleep(1) # page display (and update) autocompletion when you make little longer delay 
    
    # --- select using arrow key ---
    
    # move selection on list and accept it
    #search_text_box.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    #search_text_box.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    #search_text_box.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    #search_text_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    
    # OR
    
    # --- select using tag `<li>` and `text()` in autocompletion --- 
    
    # click on first matching item on list
    #one_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(text(),'Dress')]")))
    one_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='ac_results']//li[contains(text(),'Dress')]")))
    
    print(' tag:', one_option.tag_name)
    print('text:', one_option.text)
    print('bold:', one_option.find_element_by_xpath('.//strong').text)
    
    one_option.click()

    # OR

    # --- get all elements in autocompletion using `<li>` tag --- 

    # get many matching items and use [index] to click on some item on list
    #one_option = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(text(),'Dress')]")))
    #all_options = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Dress')]")
    #for option in all_options:
    #    print(option.tag_name, ':', option.text)
    #all_options[1].click()
    
    print(' current:', driver.current_url)
    print('expected:', "http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=3&controller=product")
    print('the same:', driver.current_url == "http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=3&controller=product")

    assert "http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=3&controller=product" == driver.current_url, "This Test case is fallied"
    #assertEqual("http://automationpractice.com/index.php?id_product=3&controller=product", self.driver.current_url, "This Test case is fallied")
    
except NoSuchElementException as e:
     print('NoSuchElementException:', e)
except TimeoutException as e:
     print('TimeoutException:', e)
except AssertionError as e:
     print('AssertionError:', e)
```